# Number of minutes between the two dates depending on the status

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I have a question related to Sql Server 2005 ( Tsql)

I have two columns
Date 
Status

And the Data looks.. like

```
Date                    Status

2012-09-01 00:01:00.000 2

2012-09-01 04:17:00.000 4

2012-09-01 04:34:00.000 4

2012-09-01 04:35:00.000 4

2012-09-01 04:35:48.000 4

2012-09-01 04:35:51.000 1

2012-09-01 17:28:25.000 2

2012-09-01 23:58:00.000 4

2012-09-01 23:59:00.000 1
```

I need to calculate the time difference between the status ... for example. for min time is when 
status 2 start and max time when status= 1 (stop) between that date i want the number of minutes. 
I have done through the cursors checking the status and recording the minumum time and maximum time in the variables

Do we have any easy of doing it using CTE.

MY QUERY TAKES LONG TIME TO FINISH ... PLEASE HELP.

```
   DECLARE @pdunitid INT
        DECLARE @Date DATETIME
        DECLARE @pddatetime DATETIME
        DECLARE @pdstatus INT
        DECLARE @starttime DATETIME
        DECLARE @endTime DATETIME
        DECLARE @calc INT
        DECLARE @Totaltime INT
        DECLARE @START INT


        SET @pdunitid = 33568906
        SET @Date = GETDATE() - 102
        set @Totaltime = 0
        SET @calc = 0
        SET @START = 0


        DECLARE s CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR
        SELECT pddatetime,pdstatus FROM s1 WITH (NOLOCK)
        WHERE  pdunitid = @pdUnitid
        AND CONVERT(VARCHAR,pddatetime,112) = CONVERT(VARCHAR,@Date,112)
        ORDER BY pddatetime,pdstatus 

        OPEN s 

        FETCH NEXT FROM s INTO @pddatetime,@pdstatus
        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
            BEGIN
                -- status 2 is for start sometimes you don't get start so you will have to use the first date with status 4

                IF pdstatus IN (2,4)  AND @START = 0 
                    BEGIN 
                        SET @starttime = @pddatetime
                        SET @START = 1
                    END

                -- status 1 is for stop 

                IF (@pdstatus= 1) 
                    BEGIN 
                        SET @endTime = @pddatetime
                        SET @calc = 1   
                    END

                -- if you dont get the status 1 by '23:59:00' take the end time


            IF  convert(varchar,@pdgpsdatetime,108) = '23:59:00'
                    BEGIN 
                        SET @endTime = @pddatetime
                        SET @calc = 1   
            END

                -- Calculate the minutes.

                IF @calc = 1 
                    BEGIN 
                        SET @Totaltime = @Totaltime + DATEDIFF(mi, @starttime,@endTime)
                        SET @calc = 0   
                        SET @START = 0
                    END
        FETCH NEXT FROM s INTO @pddatetime,@pdstatus
            END
        CLOSE s
        DEALLOCATE s

        SELECT  @Totaltime
```

Comment: please add your query that you have written.

Comment: Are you using a Cursor? These are not very efficient. Are the columns indexed? Post the TSQL that you have attempted.

Comment: I have posted by query also... and commented where ever it is required..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, instead of `#tbl` put your table name:

```
DROP TABLE #tbl
CREATE TABLE #tbl([Date] DATETIME, [Status] INT)
INSERT  #tbl
VALUES  
('2012-09-01 00:01:00.000',  2),
('2012-09-01 04:17:00.000',  4),
('2012-09-01 04:34:00.000',  4),
('2012-09-01 04:35:00.000',  4),
('2012-09-01 04:35:48.000',  4),
('2012-09-01 04:35:51.000',  1),
('2012-09-01 17:28:25.000',  2),
('2012-09-01 23:58:00.000',  4),
('2012-09-01 23:59:00.000',  1),

-- for 2012-09-05 there are no statuses 1 or 2
--('2012-09-05 00:01:00.000',  2),
('2012-09-05 04:17:00.000',  4),
('2012-09-05 04:34:00.000',  4),
('2012-09-05 04:35:00.000',  4),
('2012-09-05 04:35:48.000',  4),
('2012-09-05 04:35:51.000',  4),
('2012-09-05 17:28:25.000',  4),
('2012-09-05 23:58:00.000',  4)
--('2012-09-05 23:59:00.000',  1)

;WITH tbl AS 
(
    SELECT  *,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Date]) id
    FROM    #tbl
), 
b AS 
(
    SELECT  MIN([Date]) MinDate,
            MAX([Date]) MaxDate,
            CAST([Date] AS DATE) dateWithoutTime
    FROM    tbl
    GROUP   BY CAST([Date] AS DATE)
),
a AS
(
    SELECT  *,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Date]) num
    FROM    tbl
    LEFT JOIN 
            b ON 
            b.MaxDate = [Date]
    OR      b.MinDate = [Date]
    WHERE   [Status] IN (2, 1)
    OR      [Date] = CASE WHEN NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #tbl c WHERE c.Status = 2 AND CAST(c.[Date] AS DATE) = b.dateWithoutTime) THEN b.MinDate END
    OR      [Date] = CASE WHEN NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #tbl c WHERE c.Status = 1 AND CAST(c.[Date] AS DATE) = b.dateWithoutTime) THEN b.MaxDate END
)

SELECT  
        tbl.Date,
        tbl.Status,
        CASE WHEN a2.num % 2 = 0 THEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE, a1.Date, a2.Date) END Diff
FROM    tbl
LEFT JOIN   
        a a2 ON tbl.id = a2.id
LEFT JOIN   
        a a1 ON a2.num = a1.num + 1
ORDER BY [Date]
```

Comment: Thanks Man you are quick.. slightly changed in the data sometimes you will not get the status 2 at it will be ('2012-09-01 00:01:00.000',  4) and end of the day at it will be ('2012-09-01 23:59:00.000',  4) so they start will be the first record and end will be last record and in between you may have 2 and 1 also.. Can you help.. please

Comment: Hi ivan, i have commented on your query can you have a look and any thoughts on this please..

Comment: I added the new functionality, the query is somewhat larger now, it handles situations when there are statuses 2 and 1 (respectively) and situation when there is no 2 nor 1 status during the entire day (I added this situation to test data). Are those only possible scenarios? Can there be a situation where you have, for instance, status 1 followed by 2 or only status 1 during the entire day?

Comment: there is no other possible scenarios.. i have breakdown your query into temp tables and excuted it works.. however when i run they same with the using the cte is taking more then 10 min i thought i am having 706 records to 1500 records per each unit and the table as over the million records.. and it is much slower... Any thoughts...

Comment: I noticed the same thing, sometimes when I use table variables or CTE's instead of temporary tables query that uses them slows down very much, I don't know what is the reason for this...

Comment: but it works.. using the temporary tables for now i am ok.. thanks for your time much appreciated..

Comment: That's great, you're welcome. Make sure you test it on your data. If you find the answer correct you can mark it as such...

Comment: Hi.. i have posted one more question if you can have a look